# How do the elemental gems influence my magic attacks?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

When I use a magic attack with multiple gems of a different type in Chantelise, the nature of the attack seems to be determined by one of the gems I use(i.e. if there's an earth and a wind gem used together I might end up with a hammerorb that has wind properties. In this case, the nature of my attack would be earth, or a hammerorb). However, there are some cases where I specifically want the magical attack to not be of a certain nature; for example, if I'm attacking a bomb-type enemy, I don't want my spell to turn out to be a hammerorb, forcing me to get up close to inflict damage.

What determines the nature of my magic attack? Is it based on the ordering of the gems, or the number of gems of each type that I put into the attack? Or is it entirely random?

Also, what sort of attributes does each gem type add to my attack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The first gemstone you cast from determines the element of the spell**. This is shown in the color of the magic circle that forms. For example, if you start off with Red, you'll get a Fire spell with a Red magic circle around your feet. Don't forget to [reorder your gemstones](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26716/can-you-reorder-magic-stones-after-you-pick-them-up-in-chantelise) if you end up with the wrong element to start.

Further gemstones will augment them in specific ways, but the **order does not matter past the first gemstone**. Red-Red-Yellow is the same spell as Red-Yellow-Red. Order is instead just for planning out your spells that will come afterwards.

The quantity of gemstones affect how much of an augment they provide, *unless* they are of the same color as the spell you are casting. If the element matches, it instead changes what spell you will be casting. As a consequence, you cannot provide an augment from a gemstone to the elemental spells that correspond to it (no attack boost on Fire spells, etc.). The below are the augments with respect to the attack spells - Heal and Super Armor have unique effects since they cannot split or add status ailments.

- Red gemstones increase attack power. The more red, the more power.
- Blue gemstones add status ailments, either poison or paralysis. This is dependent on the specific spell, with additional blue either adding the other ailment or strengthening the poison/paralysis effect.
- Green gemstones increase the number of spells fired. Additional green means more shots fired.
- Yellow gemstones increase the "duration" of the spell. For spells like Air Tornado, this makes it last longer. For projectile spells like Fireball, it increases the number of times it can hit, by giving it a piercing effect. More yellow means a longer duration boost.

**If you supply multiple colors, then you will add each of those augments at the same time**. For example, *Blue-Red-Green-Yellow* would shoot three Aqua Jets with increased damage that each hit twice (and, as far as spells using all 4, it's one of the more useful). As noted, the order still doesn't matter past the first gem.

Comment: What about multi-color spells then? Say red-blue-green. Will that be a fire spell with *both* a status ailment and additional shots fired?

Comment: @Fallen Yep. Each gem basically adds each augment. So if you did Yellow-Red-Blue-Green, you'd be surrounded by 2, higher-damage paralyzing Hammer Balls. I'll add that to my answer.